# Is the alien inevitable?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

At the end of Prometheus we get to see the famous alien of Alien.

It's born through the following steps:

1. David (the android) infects Dr. Holloway with the black liquid
2. Holloway impregnates Dr. Shaw with a creature that grows to be a ginormous facehugger
3. The ginormous facehugger implants an egg into the chest of one of the Engineers
4. The egg hatches into an alien

Is the alien as we know it the inevitable consequence of the black liquid, or would a different type of creature have resulted if a different bunch of individuals / species were involved in the process.

Comment: I note you have undone my edit.  I added those spoiler tags, as the steps you have outlined are, well, *spoilers*!

Comment: @N_Soong I didn't like the formatting you applied.  Also, the movie came out over three years ago.

Comment: @LV-426 It doesn't matter how long ago the movie came out, there will still be people who haven't seen it. As far as I am aware, we are meant to err on the side of caution when it comes to spoilers.

Comment: I added a spoiler note to the title (pending peer review) so people who haven't seen Prometheus can avoid the question.  This doesn't edit the body of the question, so I think it's a pretty good compromise.

Comment: @Liesmith I approved that spoiler note. Some sort of spoiler awareness is always appreciated.

Comment: Related discussion on [moratoriums on spoilers](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1561/5184) and [our general spoiler policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/968/5184). TL;DR: it's up to you, but the fact that the movie is three years old is inconsequential.

Comment: If I wasn't such a stickler, I'd upvote this for your name alone.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - By that logic, we should put spoiler tags on literally every single question.

Comment: @Liesmith - The policy for spoilers specifically says that you shouldn't put the word "spoiler" in the title.  See the second link in phantom's comment.

Comment: If you follow the comics rather than the movies, Aliens were native specie on one of distant planets. What's more scary, they weren't even dominant specie.

Comment: @WadCheber That link repeatedly says "there's no policy on spoilers".  Not putting the word "spoiler" in the title is one person's *personal* opinion, and they say "it looks ugly IMO".  That hardly seems a reason to avoid doing it when it seems rational to do so.

Comment: @Liesmith - Phantom described it as a policy, so I did too.

Comment: @WadCheber For a lot of questions, we do use spoiler tags. I can't think of many questions about the plot of a piece of work that don't warrant a spoiler tag at some point.

Comment: The biggest problem with this question is that it assumes the creatures we see in "Prometheus" are the same ones we know from the Aliens franchise. Statements by Ridley Scott seem to indicate that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the alien is an inevitable consequence of the black liquid, but it does take on some of the qualities of the species it hatches in. The aliens born from humans look a bit different (more humanoid) than e.g. the alien from *Alien 3* (bursts out of a dog and is a bit more animalistic) or the one at the end *Prometheus* (which comes out of the Engineer).

Comment: Or the one in predator vs alien which comes out of a predator and looks far more predator-like.  Now I want to see some iddy biddy mouse-aliens with terrifying black alien skin and little twitchy mouse noses.

Comment: @Murphy You get to see an iddy bity bug alien in the intro in the extended intro sequence to Alien Ressurection. Makes absolutely zero sense at all, but it's there and gets a closeup on it's mandibles.

Answer (score 1):

The Black Goo is called *Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15*. It is a virulent mutagenic pathogen that, when consumed, causes the hosts cells to mutate. This suggests that the host is a necessary parameter in the mutation, and, as such, the host's genetic make-up could affect the outcome of the Human (or non-human) hybrid.

From the [AVP fan wesbite](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)

> It is not known if his [Holloway's] sperm was mutated causing an
>   abnormal conception or if he was simply carrying a Trilobite that
>   moved into Shaw, though the latter seems more probable given that Shaw
>   was sterile. Whether Trilobites prefer to move into female subjects or
>   if Holloway would have naturally given "birth" to the Trilobite is
>   unknown.
>
> Although Shaw was exposed to the infected Holloway and had sex with
>   him, she was not infected with the liquid and only received the
>   Trilobite embryo. This suggests that the Black Liquid itself is not
>   sexually transmitted, but it affects the host's reproductive system

For the direct quote, see the page explaining [Chemical A0-3959X.91-15](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Chemical_A0-3959X.91_%E2%80%93_15)